# JavaScript UDF in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to utilize the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) functions in Snowflake.

I've configured it in Snowflake to work as a UDF, but, I'm getting a recursion error when I use the function in a select from a table with more than 1 row.

> JavaScript execution error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in DATEJS at '  Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString;Date.prototype.toString=function(format){' position 82 stackstrace: DATEJS.Date.toString line: 199 DATEJS.Date.toString line: 228 DATEJS.Date.toString line: 228...[snip]

This is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datejs (datein string)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS '
{

var dateIn = DATEIN;

/**
 * [Copyright info snipped]
 */
Date.CultureInfo={
    name:"en-US",englishName:"English (United States)",nativeName:"English (United States)",
    dayNames:["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
    abbreviatedDayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],
    shortestDayNames:["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
    firstLetterDayNames:["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"],
    monthNames:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    abbreviatedMonthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
    amDesignator:"AM",pmDesignator:"PM",firstDayOfWeek:0,twoDigitYearMax:2029,dateElementOrder:"mdy",
    formatPatterns:{
        shortDate:"M/d/yyyy",longDate:"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",shortTime:"h:mm tt",longTime:"h:mm:ss tt",
        fullDateTime:"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",sortableDateTime:"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
        universalSortableDateTime:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ",rfc1123:"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT",
        monthDay:"MMMM dd",yearMonth:"MMMM, yyyy"},
    regexPatterns:{
        jan:/^jan(uary)?/i,feb:/^feb(ruary)?/i,mar:/^mar(ch)?/i,apr:/^apr(il)?/i,may:/^may/i,jun:/^jun(e)?/i,jul:/^jul(y)?/i,
        aug:/^aug(ust)?/i,sep:/^sep(t(ember)?)?/i,oct:/^oct(ober)?/i,nov:/^nov(ember)?/i,dec:/^dec(ember)?/i,
        sun:/^su(n(day)?)?/i,mon:/^mo(n(day)?)?/i,tue:/^tu(e(s(day)?)?)?/i,wed:/^we(d(nesday)?)?/i,thu:/^th(u(r(s(day)?)?)?)?/i,fri:/^fr(i(day)?)?/i,sat:/^sa(t(urday)?)?/i,
        future:/^next/i,past:/^last|past|prev(ious)?/i,add:/^(\\+|after|from)/i,subtract:/^(\\-|before|ago)/i,yesterday:/^yesterday/i,today:/^t(oday)?/i,
        tomorrow:/^tomorrow/i,now:/^n(ow)?/i,millisecond:/^ms|milli(second)?s?/i,second:/^sec(ond)?s?/i,minute:/^min(ute)?s?/i,
        hour:/^h(ou)?rs?/i,week:/^w(ee)?k/i,month:/^m(o(nth)?s?)?/i,day:/^d(ays?)?/i,year:/^y((ea)?rs?)?/i,shortMeridian:/^(a|p)/i,
        longMeridian:/^(a\\.?m?\\.?|p\\.?m?\\.?)/i,timezone:/^((e(s|d)t|c(s|d)t|m(s|d)t|p(s|d)t)|((gmt)?\\s*(\\+|\\-)\\s*\\d\d\\d\\d?)|gmt)/i,
        ordinalSuffix:/^\\s*(st|nd|rd|th)/i,timeContext:/^\\s*(\\:|a|p)/i
        },
    abbreviatedTimeZoneStandard:{GMT:"-000",EST:"-0400",CST:"-0500",MST:"-0600",PST:"-0700"},
    abbreviatedTimeZoneDST:{GMT:"-000",EDT:"-0500",CDT:"-0600",MDT:"-0700",PDT:"-0800"}
    };

Date.getMonthNumberFromName=function(name){
    var n=Date.CultureInfo.monthNames,
        m=Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedMonthNames,
        s=name.toLowerCase();
    for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++){if(n[i].toLowerCase()==s||m[i].toLowerCase()==s){return i;}}
    return-1;
    };

Date.getDayNumberFromName=function(name){
    var n=Date.CultureInfo.dayNames,
        m=Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedDayNames,
        o=Date.CultureInfo.shortestDayNames,
        s=name.toLowerCase();
    for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++){
        if(n[i].toLowerCase()==s||m[i].toLowerCase()==s){return i;}
        }
    return-1;
    };

Date.isLeapYear=function(year){return(((year%4===0)&&(year%100!==0))||(year%400===0));};

Date.getDaysInMonth=function(year,month){return[31,(Date.isLeapYear(year)?29:28),31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][month];};

Date.getTimezoneOffset=function(s,dst){return(dst||false)?Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedTimeZoneDST[s.toUpperCase()]:Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedTimeZoneStandard[s.toUpperCase()];};

Date.getTimezoneAbbreviation=function(offset,dst){
    var n=(dst||false)?Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedTimeZoneDST:Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedTimeZoneStandard,p;
    for(p in n){if(n[p]===offset){return p;}}
    return null;
    };

Date.prototype.clone=function(){return new Date(this.getTime());};

Date.prototype.compareTo=function(date){
    if(isNaN(this)){throw new Error(this);}
    if(date instanceof Date&&!isNaN(date)){return(this>date)?1:(this<date)?-1:0;}
    else{throw new TypeError(date);}
    };

Date.prototype.equals=function(date){return(this.compareTo(date)===0);};

Date.prototype.between=function(start,end){var t=this.getTime();return t>=start.getTime()&&t<=end.getTime();};

Date.prototype.addMilliseconds=function(value){this.setMilliseconds(this.getMilliseconds()+value);return this;};

Date.prototype.addSeconds=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*1000);};

Date.prototype.addMinutes=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*60000);};

Date.prototype.addHours=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*3600000);};

Date.prototype.addDays=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*86400000);};

Date.prototype.addWeeks=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*604800000);};

Date.prototype.addMonths=function(value){var n=this.getDate();this.setDate(1);this.setMonth(this.getMonth()+value);this.setDate(Math.min(n,this.getDaysInMonth()));return this;};

Date.prototype.addYears=function(value){return this.addMonths(value*12);};

Date.prototype.add=function(config){
    if(typeof config=="number"){this._orient=config;return this;}
    var x=config;if(x.millisecond||x.milliseconds){this.addMilliseconds(x.millisecond||x.milliseconds);}
    if(x.second||x.seconds){this.addSeconds(x.second||x.seconds);}
    if(x.minute||x.minutes){this.addMinutes(x.minute||x.minutes);}
    if(x.hour||x.hours){this.addHours(x.hour||x.hours);}
    if(x.month||x.months){this.addMonths(x.month||x.months);}
    if(x.year||x.years){this.addYears(x.year||x.years);}
    if(x.day||x.days){this.addDays(x.day||x.days);}
    return this;
    };

Date._validate=function(value,min,max,name){
    if(typeof value!="number"){throw new TypeError(value+" is not a Number.");}
    else if(value<min||value>max){throw new RangeError(value+" is not a valid value for "+name+".");}
    return true;
    };

Date.validateMillisecond=function(n){return Date._validate(n,0,999,"milliseconds");};

Date.validateSecond=function(n){return Date._validate(n,0,59,"seconds");};

Date.validateMinute=function(n){return Date._validate(n,0,59,"minutes");};

Date.validateHour=function(n){return Date._validate(n,0,23,"hours");};

Date.validateDay=function(n,year,month){return Date._validate(n,1,Date.getDaysInMonth(year,month),"days");};

Date.validateMonth=function(n){return Date._validate(n,0,11,"months");};

Date.validateYear=function(n){return Date._validate(n,1,9999,"seconds");};

Date.prototype.set=function(config){
    var x=config;
    if(!x.millisecond&&x.millisecond!==0){x.millisecond=-1;}
    if(!x.second&&x.second!==0){x.second=-1;}
    if(!x.minute&&x.minute!==0){x.minute=-1;}
    if(!x.hour&&x.hour!==0){x.hour=-1;}
    if(!x.day&&x.day!==0){x.day=-1;}
    if(!x.month&&x.month!==0){x.month=-1;}
    if(!x.year&&x.year!==0){x.year=-1;}
    if(x.millisecond!=-1&&Date.validateMillisecond(x.millisecond)){this.addMilliseconds(x.millisecond-this.getMilliseconds());}
    if(x.second!=-1&&Date.validateSecond(x.second)){this.addSeconds(x.second-this.getSeconds());}
    if(x.minute!=-1&&Date.validateMinute(x.minute)){this.addMinutes(x.minute-this.getMinutes());}
    if(x.hour!=-1&&Date.validateHour(x.hour)){this.addHours(x.hour-this.getHours());}
    if(x.month!==-1&&Date.validateMonth(x.month)){this.addMonths(x.month-this.getMonth());}
    if(x.year!=-1&&Date.validateYear(x.year)){this.addYears(x.year-this.getFullYear());}
    if(x.day!=-1&&Date.validateDay(x.day,this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth())){this.addDays(x.day-this.getDate());}
    if(x.timezone){this.setTimezone(x.timezone);}
    if(x.timezoneOffset){this.setTimezoneOffset(x.timezoneOffset);}
    return this;
};

Date.prototype.clearTime=function(){this.setHours(0);this.setMinutes(0);this.setSeconds(0);this.setMilliseconds(0);return this;};

Date.prototype.isLeapYear=function(){var y=this.getFullYear();return(((y%4===0)&&(y%100!==0))||(y%400===0));};

Date.prototype.isWeekday=function(){return!(this.is().sat()||this.is().sun());};

Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth=function(){return Date.getDaysInMonth(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth());};

Date.prototype.moveToFirstDayOfMonth=function(){return this.set({day:1});};

Date.prototype.moveToLastDayOfMonth=function(){return this.set({day:this.getDaysInMonth()});};

Date.prototype.moveToDayOfWeek=function(day,orient){var diff=(day-this.getDay()+7*(orient||+1))%7;return this.addDays((diff===0)?diff+=7*(orient||+1):diff);};

Date.prototype.moveToMonth=function(month,orient){var diff=(month-this.getMonth()+12*(orient||+1))%12;return this.addMonths((diff===0)?diff+=12*(orient||+1):diff);};

Date.prototype.getDayOfYear=function(){return Math.floor((this-new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1))/86400000);};

Date.prototype.getWeekOfYear=function(firstDayOfWeek){
    var y=this.getFullYear(),
        m=this.getMonth(),
        d=this.getDate();
    var dow=firstDayOfWeek||Date.CultureInfo.firstDayOfWeek;
    var offset=7+1-new Date(y,0,1).getDay();
    if(offset==8){offset=1;}
    var daynum=((Date.UTC(y,m,d,0,0,0)-Date.UTC(y,0,1,0,0,0))/86400000)+1;
    var w=Math.floor((daynum-offset+7)/7);
    if(w===dow){y--;var prevOffset=7+1-new Date(y,0,1).getDay();
    if(prevOffset==2||prevOffset==8){w=53;}else{w=52;}}
    return w;
    };

Date.prototype.isDST=function(){console.log("isDST");return this.toString().match(/(E|C|M|P)(S|D)T/)[2]=="D";};

Date.prototype.getTimezone=function(){return Date.getTimezoneAbbreviation(this.getUTCOffset,this.isDST());};

Date.prototype.setTimezoneOffset=function(s){var here=this.getTimezoneOffset(),there=Number(s)*-6/10;this.addMinutes(there-here);return this;};

Date.prototype.setTimezone=function(s){return this.setTimezoneOffset(Date.getTimezoneOffset(s));};

Date.prototype.getUTCOffset=function(){var n=this.getTimezoneOffset()*-10/6,r;if(n<0){r=(n-10000).toString();return r[0]+r.substr(2);}else{r=(n+10000).toString();return"+"+r.substr(1);}};

Date.prototype.getDayName=function(abbrev){return abbrev?Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedDayNames[this.getDay()]:Date.CultureInfo.dayNames[this.getDay()];};

Date.prototype.getMonthName=function(abbrev){return abbrev?Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedMonthNames[this.getMonth()]:Date.CultureInfo.monthNames[this.getMonth()];};

Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString;

Date.prototype.toString=function(format){
    var self=this;
    var p=function p(s){
        return(s.toString().length==1)?"0"+s:s;};
    return format?format.replace(
        /dd?d?d?|MM?M?M?|yy?y?y?|hh?|HH?|mm?|ss?|tt?|zz?z?/g,
            function(format){
                switch(format){
                    case"hh":return p(self.getHours()<13?self.getHours():(self.getHours()-12));
                    case"h":return self.getHours()<13?self.getHours():(self.getHours()-12);
                    case"HH":return p(self.getHours());
                    case"H":return self.getHours();
                    case"mm":return p(self.getMinutes());
                    case"m":return self.getMinutes();
                    case"ss":return p(self.getSeconds());
                    case"s":return self.getSeconds();
                    case"yyyy":return self.getFullYear();
                    case"yy":return self.getFullYear().toString().substring(2,4);
                    case"dddd":return self.getDayName();
                    case"ddd":return self.getDayName(true);
                    case"dd":return p(self.getDate());
                    case"d":return self.getDate().toString();
                    case"MMMM":return self.getMonthName();
                    case"MMM":return self.getMonthName(true);
                    case"MM":return p((self.getMonth()+1));
                    case"M":return self.getMonth()+1;
                    case"t":return self.getHours()<12?Date.CultureInfo.amDesignator.substring(0,1):Date.CultureInfo.pmDesignator.substring(0,1);
                    case"tt":return self.getHours()<12?Date.CultureInfo.amDesignator:Date.CultureInfo.pmDesignator;
                    case"zzz":case"zz":case"z":return"";
                    }
            }
        ):this._toString();
    };

Date.now=function(){return new Date();};

Date.today=function(){return Date.now().clearTime();};

Date.prototype._orient=+1;Date.prototype.next=function(){this._orient=+1;return this;};

Date.prototype.last=Date.prototype.prev=Date.prototype.previous=function(){this._orient=-1;return this;};

Date.prototype._is=false;

Date.prototype.is=function(){this._is=true;return this;};

Number.prototype._dateElement="day";Number.prototype.fromNow=function(){var c={};c[this._dateElement]=this;return Date.now().add(c);};

Number.prototype.ago=function(){var c={};c[this._dateElement]=this*-1;return Date.now().add(c);};

(function(){
    var $D=Date.prototype,$N=Number.prototype;
    var dx=("sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday").split(/\\s/),
        mx=("january february march april may june july august september october november december").split(/\\s/),
        px=("Millisecond Second Minute Hour Day Week Month Year").split(/\\s/),de;
    var df=function(n){
        return function(){
            if(this._is){this._is=false;return this.getDay()==n;}
            return this.moveToDayOfWeek(n,this._orient);
            };
        };
    for(var i=0;i<dx.length;i++){$D[dx[i]]=$D[dx[i].substring(0,3)]=df(i);}
    var mf=function(n){
        return function(){
            if(this._is){this._is=false;return this.getMonth()===n;}
            return this.moveToMonth(n,this._orient);
            };
        };
    for(var j=0;j<mx.length;j++){$D[mx[j]]=$D[mx[j].substring(0,3)]=mf(j);}
    var ef=function(j){
        return function(){
            if(j.substring(j.length-1)!="s"){j+="s";}
            return this["add"+j](this._orient);
            };
        };
    var nf=function(n){return function(){this._dateElement=n;return this;};};
    for(var k=0;k<px.length;k++){de=px[k].toLowerCase();$D[de]=$D[de+"s"]=ef(px[k]);$N[de]=$N[de+"s"]=nf(de);}
    }());

Date.prototype.toJSONString=function(){return this.toString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");};

Date.prototype.toShortDateString=function(){return this.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDatePattern);};

Date.prototype.toLongDateString=function(){return this.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.longDatePattern);};

Date.prototype.toShortTimeString=function(){return this.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortTimePattern);};

Date.prototype.toLongTimeString=function(){return this.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.longTimePattern);};

Date.prototype.getOrdinal=function(){switch(this.getDate()){case 1:case 21:case 31:return"st";case 2:case 22:return"nd";case 3:case 23:return"rd";default:return"th";}};

(function(){
    Date.Parsing={
        Exception:function(s){this.message="Parse error at \'"+s.substring(0,10)+" ...\'";}
        };

        var $P=Date.Parsing;
        var _=$P.Operators={
            rtoken:function(r){
                return function(s){
                    var mx=s.match(r);
                    if(mx){return([mx[0],s.substring(mx[0].length)]);}
                    else{throw new $P.Exception(s);}
                    };
                },
            token:function(s){return function(s){return _.rtoken(new RegExp("^\\s*"+s+"\\s*"))(s);};},
            stoken:function(s){return _.rtoken(new RegExp("^"+s));},
            until:function(p){return function(s){var qx=[],rx=null;while(s.length){
                try{rx=p.call(this,s);}
                catch(e){qx.push(rx[0]);s=rx[1];continue;}
                break;
                }
            return[qx,s];};},many:function(p){
                return function(s){var rx=[],r=null;while(s.length){
                    try{r=p.call(this,s);}catch(e){return[rx,s];}
                    rx.push(r[0]);s=r[1];}
                return[rx,s];};
                },
            optional:function(p){
                return function(s){var r=null;try{r=p.call(this,s);}catch(e){return[null,s];}
                return[r[0],r[1]];};
                },
            not:function(p){
                return function(s){
                    try{p.call(this,s);}
                    catch(e){return[null,s];}
                    throw new $P.Exception(s);
                    };
                },
            ignore:function(p){return p?function(s){var r=null;r=p.call(this,s);return[null,r[1]];}:null;},
            product:function(){
                var px=arguments[0],qx=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),rx=[];
                for(var i=0;i<px.length;i++){rx.push(_.each(px[i],qx));}
                return rx;
                },
            cache:function(rule){
                var cache={},r=null;
                return function(s){
                    try{r=cache[s]=(cache[s]||rule.call(this,s));}
                    catch(e){r=cache[s]=e;}
                    if(r instanceof $P.Exception){throw r;}else{return r;}
                    };
                },
            any:function(){
                var px=arguments;
                return function(s){
                    var r=null;for(var i=0;i<px.length;i++){
                        if(px[i]==null){continue;}
                        try{r=(px[i].call(this,s));}
                        catch(e){r=null;}
                        if(r){return r;}
                        }
                    throw new $P.Exception(s);
                    };
                },
            each:function(){
                var px=arguments;
                return function(s){
                    var rx=[],r=null;for(var i=0;i<px.length;i++){
                        if(px[i]==null){continue;}
                        try{r=(px[i].call(this,s));}
                        catch(e){throw new $P.Exception(s);}
                        rx.push(r[0]);s=r[1];
                        }
                    return[rx,s];
                    };
                },
            all:function(){var px=arguments,_=_;return _.each(_.optional(px));},
            sequence:function(px,d,c){
                d=d||_.rtoken(/^\\s*/);c=c||null;
                if(px.length==1){return px[0];}
                return function(s){
                    var r=null,q=null;
                    var rx=[];
                    for(var i=0;i<px.length;i++){
                        try{r=px[i].call(this,s);}
                        catch(e){break;}
                        rx.push(r[0]);
                        try{q=d.call(this,r[1]);}
                        catch(ex){q=null;break;}
                        s=q[1];
                        }
                    if(!r){throw new $P.Exception(s);}
                    if(q){throw new $P.Exception(q[1]);}
                    if(c){try{r=c.call(this,r[1]);}catch(ey){throw new $P.Exception(r[1]);}}
                    return[rx,(r?r[1]:s)];
                    };
                },
            between:function(d1,p,d2){
                d2=d2||d1;
                var _fn=_.each(_.ignore(d1),p,_.ignore(d2));
                return function(s){var rx=_fn.call(this,s);
                return[[rx[0][0],r[0][2]],rx[1]];};
                },
            list:function(p,d,c){
                d=d||_.rtoken(/^\\s*/);c=c||null;
                return(p instanceof Array?_.each(_.product(p.slice(0,-1),_.ignore(d)),p.slice(-1),_.ignore(c)):_.each(_.many(_.each(p,_.ignore(d))),px,_.ignore(c)));
                },
            set:function(px,d,c){
                d=d||_.rtoken(/^\\s*/);c=c||null;
                return function(s){
                    var r=null,p=null,q=null,rx=null,best=[[],s],last=false;
                    for(var i=0;i<px.length;i++){
                        q=null;p=null;r=null;last=(px.length==1);
                        try{r=px[i].call(this,s);}
                        catch(e){continue;}
                        rx=[[r[0]],r[1]];if(r[1].length>0&&!last){try{q=d.call(this,r[1]);}catch(ex){last=true;}}else{last=true;}
                        if(!last&&q[1].length===0){last=true;}
                        if(!last){
                            var qx=[];
                            for(var j=0;j<px.length;j++){if(i!=j){qx.push(px[j]);}}
                            p=_.set(qx,d).call(this,q[1]);
                            if(p[0].length>0){rx[0]=rx[0].concat(p[0]);rx[1]=p[1];}
                            }
                        if(rx[1].length<best[1].length){best=rx;}
                        if(best[1].length===0){break;}
                        }
                    if(best[0].length===0){return best;}
                    if(c){
                        try{q=c.call(this,best[1]);}
                        catch(ey){throw new $P.Exception(best[1]);}
                        best[1]=q[1];
                            }
                    return best;
                    };
                },
            forward:function(gr,fname){return function(s){return gr[fname].call(this,s);};},
            replace:function(rule,repl){return function(s){var r=rule.call(this,s);return[repl,r[1]];};},
            process:function(rule,fn){return function(s){var r=rule.call(this,s);return[fn.call(this,r[0]),r[1]];};},
            min:function(min,rule){
                return function(s){var rx=rule.call(this,s);if(rx[0].length<min){throw new $P.Exception(s);}
                return rx;};
                }
            };

    var _generator=function(op){
        return function(){
            var args=null,rx=[];
            if(arguments.length>1){args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);}
            else if(arguments[0]instanceof Array){args=arguments[0];}
            if(args){
                for(var i=0,px=args.shift();i<px.length;i++){args.unshift(px[i]);rx.push(op.apply(null,args));args.shift();return rx;}
                }
            else{return op.apply(null,arguments);}
            };
        };

    var gx="optional not ignore cache".split(/\\s/);
    for(var i=0;i<gx.length;i++){_[gx[i]]=_generator(_[gx[i]]);}
    var _vector=function(op){
        return function(){if(arguments[0]instanceof Array){return op.apply(null,arguments[0]);}else{return op.apply(null,arguments);}};
        };
    var vx="each any all".split(/\\s/);
    for(var j=0;j<vx.length;j++){_[vx[j]]=_vector(_[vx[j]]);}
    }());

(function(){
    var flattenAndCompact=function(ax){
        var rx=[];
        for(var i=0;i<ax.length;i++){
            if(ax[i]instanceof Array){rx=rx.concat(flattenAndCompact(ax[i]));}
            else{if(ax[i]){rx.push(ax[i]);}}
            }
        return rx;
    };

    Date.Grammar={};
    Date.Translator={
        hour:function(s){return function(){this.hour=Number(s);};},
        minute:function(s){return function(){this.minute=Number(s);};},
        second:function(s){return function(){this.second=Number(s);};},
        meridian:function(s){return function(){this.meridian=s.slice(0,1).toLowerCase();};},
        timezone:function(s){
            return function(){
                var n=s.replace(/[^\\d\\+\\-]/g,"");
                if(n.length){this.timezoneOffset=Number(n);}
                else{this.timezone=s.toLowerCase();}
                };
            },
        day:function(x){var s=x[0];return function(){this.day=Number(s.match(/\\d+/)[0]);};},
        month:function(s){return function(){this.month=((s.length==3)?Date.getMonthNumberFromName(s):(Number(s)-1));};},
        year:function(s){return function(){var n=Number(s);this.year=((s.length>2)?n:(n+(((n+2000)<Date.CultureInfo.twoDigitYearMax)?2000:1900)));};},
        rday:function(s){return function(){switch(s){case"yesterday":this.days=-1;break;case"tomorrow":this.days=1;break;case"today":this.days=0;break;case"now":this.days=0;this.now=true;break;}};},
        finishExact:function(x){
            x=(x instanceof Array)?x:[x];var now=new Date();
            this.year=now.getFullYear();
            this.month=now.getMonth();
            this.day=1;
            this.hour=0;
            this.minute=0;
            this.second=0;
            for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){if(x[i]){x[i].call(this);}}
            this.hour=(this.meridian=="p"&&this.hour<13)?this.hour+12:this.hour;
            if(this.day>Date.getDaysInMonth(this.year,this.month)){
                throw new RangeError(this.day+" is not a valid value for days.");}
            var r=new Date(this.year,this.month,this.day,this.hour,this.minute,this.second);
            if(this.timezone){r.set({timezone:this.timezone});}
            else if(this.timezoneOffset){r.set({timezoneOffset:this.timezoneOffset});}
            return r;
            },
        finish:function(x){
            x=(x instanceof Array)?flattenAndCompact(x):[x];if(x.length===0){return null;}
            for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){if(typeof x[i]=="function"){x[i].call(this);}}
            if(this.now){return new Date();}
            var today=Date.today();
            var method=null;
            var expression=!!(this.days!=null||this.orient||this.operator);
            if(expression){
                var gap,mod,orient;orient=((this.orient=="past"||this.operator=="subtract")?-1:1);
                if(this.weekday){this.unit="day";gap=(Date.getDayNumberFromName(this.weekday)-today.getDay());mod=7;this.days=gap?((gap+(orient*mod))%mod):(orient*mod);}
                if(this.month){this.unit="month";gap=(this.month-today.getMonth());mod=12;this.months=gap?((gap+(orient*mod))%mod):(orient*mod);this.month=null;}
                if(!this.unit){this.unit="day";}
                if(this[this.unit+"s"]==null||this.operator!=null){
                    if(!this.value){this.value=1;}
                    if(this.unit=="week"){this.unit="day";this.value=this.value*7;}
                    this[this.unit+"s"]=this.value*orient;
                    }
                return today.add(this);
                }
            else{
                if(this.meridian&&this.hour){this.hour=(this.hour<13&&this.meridian=="p")?this.hour+12:this.hour;}
                if(this.weekday&&!this.day){this.day=(today.addDays((Date.getDayNumberFromName(this.weekday)-today.getDay()))).getDate();}
                if(this.month&&!this.day){this.day=1;}
                return today.set(this);
                }
            }
        };

    var _=Date.Parsing.Operators,
        g=Date.Grammar,
        t=Date.Translator,_fn;
    g.datePartDelimiter=_.rtoken(/^([\\s\\-\\.\\,\\/\\x27]+)/);
    g.timePartDelimiter=_.stoken(":");
    g.whiteSpace=_.rtoken(/^\\s*/);
    g.generalDelimiter=_.rtoken(/^(([\\s\\,]|at|on)+)/);
    var _C={};
    g.ctoken=function(keys){
        var fn=_C[keys];if(!fn){
            var c=Date.CultureInfo.regexPatterns;
            var kx=keys.split(/\\s+/),px=[];
            for(var i=0;i<kx.length;i++){px.push(_.replace(_.rtoken(c[kx[i]]),kx[i]));}
            fn=_C[keys]=_.any.apply(null,px);
            }
        return fn;
        };
    g.ctoken2=function(key){return _.rtoken(Date.CultureInfo.regexPatterns[key]);};
    g.h=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])/),t.hour));
    g.hh=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/),t.hour));
    g.H=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])/),t.hour));
    g.HH=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])/),t.hour));
    g.m=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])/),t.minute));
    g.mm=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^[0-5][0-9]/),t.minute));
    g.s=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])/),t.second));
    g.ss=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^[0-5][0-9]/),t.second));
    g.hms=_.cache(_.sequence([g.H,g.mm,g.ss],g.timePartDelimiter));
    g.t=_.cache(_.process(g.ctoken2("shortMeridian"),t.meridian));
    g.tt=_.cache(_.process(g.ctoken2("longMeridian"),t.meridian));
    g.z=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\+|\\-)?\\s*\\d\\d\d\\d?/),t.timezone));
    g.zz=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\+|\\-)\\s*\\d\\d\\d\\d/),t.timezone));
    g.zzz=_.cache(_.process(g.ctoken2("timezone"),t.timezone));
    g.timeSuffix=_.each(_.ignore(g.whiteSpace),_.set([g.tt,g.zzz]));
    g.time=_.each(_.optional(_.ignore(_.stoken("T"))),g.hms,g.timeSuffix);
    g.d=_.cache(_.process(_.each(_.rtoken(/^([0-2]\\d|3[0-1]|\\d)/),_.optional(g.ctoken2("ordinalSuffix"))),t.day));
    g.dd=_.cache(_.process(_.each(_.rtoken(/^([0-2]\\d|3[0-1])/),_.optional(g.ctoken2("ordinalSuffix"))),t.day));
    g.ddd=g.dddd=_.cache(_.process(g.ctoken("sun mon tue wed thu fri sat"),function(s){return function(){this.weekday=s;};}));
    g.M=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(1[0-2]|0\\d|\\d)/),t.month));
    g.MM=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(1[0-2]|0\\d)/),t.month));
    g.MMM=g.MMMM=_.cache(_.process(g.ctoken("jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec"),t.month));
    g.y=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\d\\d?)/),t.year));
    g.yy=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\d\\d)/),t.year));
    g.yyy=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\d\\d?\\d?\\d?)/),t.year));
    g.yyyy=_.cache(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(\\d\\d\\d\\d)/),t.year));
    _fn=function(){return _.each(_.any.apply(null,arguments),_.not(g.ctoken2("timeContext")));};
    g.day=_fn(g.d,g.dd);
    g.month=_fn(g.M,g.MMM);
    g.year=_fn(g.yyyy,g.yy);
    g.orientation=_.process(g.ctoken("past future"),function(s){return function(){this.orient=s;};});
    g.operator=_.process(g.ctoken("add subtract"),function(s){return function(){this.operator=s;};});
    g.rday=_.process(g.ctoken("yesterday tomorrow today now"),t.rday);
    g.unit=_.process(g.ctoken("minute hour day week month year"),function(s){return function(){this.unit=s;};});
    g.value=_.process(_.rtoken(/^\\d\\d?(st|nd|rd|th)?/),function(s){return function(){this.value=s.replace(/\\D/g,"");};});
    g.expression=_.set([g.rday,g.operator,g.value,g.unit,g.orientation,g.ddd,g.MMM]);
    _fn=function(){return _.set(arguments,g.datePartDelimiter);};
    g.mdy=_fn(g.ddd,g.month,g.day,g.year);
    g.ymd=_fn(g.ddd,g.year,g.month,g.day);
    g.dmy=_fn(g.ddd,g.day,g.month,g.year);
    g.date=function(s){return((g[Date.CultureInfo.dateElementOrder]||g.mdy).call(this,s));};
    g.format=_.process(_.many(_.any(_.process(_.rtoken(/^(dd?d?d?|MM?M?M?|yy?y?y?|hh?|HH?|mm?|ss?|tt?|zz?z?)/),function(fmt){
        if(g[fmt]){return g[fmt];}
        else{throw Date.Parsing.Exception(fmt);}
        }),_.process(_.rtoken(/^[^dMyhHmstz]+/),function(s){return _.ignore(_.stoken(s));}))),
        function(rules){return _.process(_.each.apply(null,rules),t.finishExact);});
    var _F={};
    var _get=function(f){return _F[f]=(_F[f]||g.format(f)[0]);};
    g.formats=function(fx){if(fx instanceof Array){var rx=[];for(var i=0;i<fx.length;i++){rx.push(_get(fx[i]));}
    return _.any.apply(null,rx);}else{return _get(fx);}};
    g._formats=g.formats(["yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss","ddd, MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss tt","ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz","d"]);
    g._start=_.process(_.set([g.date,g.time,g.expression],g.generalDelimiter,g.whiteSpace),t.finish);
    g.start=function(s){
        try{var r=g._formats.call({},s);if(r[1].length===0){return r;}}
        catch(e){}
        return g._start.call({},s);
        };
    }()
    );

Date._parse=Date.parse;Date.parse=function(s){
    var r=null;
    if(!s){return null;}
    try{r=Date.Grammar.start.call({},s);}catch(e){return null;}
    return((r[1].length===0)?r[0]:null);
    };

Date.getParseFunction=function(fx){
    var fn=Date.Grammar.formats(fx);
    return function(s){
        var r=null;
        try{r=fn.call({},s);}
        catch(e){return null;}
        return((r[1].length===0)?r[0]:null);
        };
    };

Date.parseExact=function(s,fx){
    return Date.getParseFunction(fx)(s);
    };

return Date.parse(dateIn);

};'
```

If I just run:

```
select datejs('2/15/2009 05:22:37')
    union all
select datejs('2012-03-29')
    union all
select datejs(null)
```

Or:

```
select d_date, datejs(d_date) from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.DATE_DIM limit 1;
```

Then I get no error and the function works. If I do a select from a table:

```
select d_date, datejs(d_date) from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.DATE_DIM limit 2;
```

Then the error occurs. Why is it that I can union multiple rows in a query, but I cannot select multiple rows from a table and expect the function to work?

Comment: It is expecting an atomic value. For example in your unions you are passing literal values to each call to the function 3 times, where in your second select statement you are trying to pass more than one. Should you not simply loop through each row in the table instead?

Comment: @jimmy8ball Hmmm- that could be true. I would have expected the setup to function like any other function in SQL when called. I had expected that it should call the function only on the value of that column in each row selected, rather than all of the selected rows at once. I've not seen other functions operate this way.

Comment: One way to prove the theory is to pass more than one set of literal values in your unions, if errors then proves the theory. build a simple loop to iterate through every row in the table.

Comment: So, what I did was make the unions into a subquery and applied the function on the outer query, and then it failed. So, it seems that you're right about it not passing values atomically. I'll have to see about trying a loop instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Snowflake does not guarantee a completely clean JavaScript environment for each row. This is for performance reasons. As a result, side effects from previous rows can affect the following rows.

In this case, let's look at this piece of code in date.js:

```
...
Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString;

Date.prototype.toString=function(format){  // REDACTED IRRELEVANT PARTS
    return ... this._toString();
}
...
```

When this code is executed twice, or more times, both `.toString` and `._toString` contain the same code, which calls `._toString`, resulting in infinite recursion.

The way to avoid it is to make sure the Date modifications happen only once. This can be achieved using the following code pattern:

```
if (typeof(setup_done) === "undefined") {  // checking if a global variable is set

  /* PUT HERE THE SETUP LOGIC */

  setup_done = true;  // setting global variable to true
}
```

Snowflake documentation today is not specific enough about this behavior, we will clarify it soon.

Comment: Thank you Marcin! I will give this a try. For the moment, I've been able to write my own UDF without referencing this library, so I'm no longer "stuck" per se. But I would like to make this function and this has been a very helpful explanation!